# jQuery.get() исходный код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как ориентироваться в src папке проекта jquery?
Где я могу найти конкретно этот jQuery.get метод?:

**/src/ajax.js** #L815

```js
    getScript: function( url, callback ) {
        return jQuery.get( url, undefined, callback, "script" );
    }
```

Тот что мне удалось найти выполняет совсем другую задачу:

**/src/core.js** #L58

```js
    // Get the Nth element in the matched element set OR
    // Get the whole matched element set as a clean array
    get: function( num ) {
        return num != null ?

            // Return just the one element from the set
            ( num < 0 ? this[ num + this.length ] : this[ num ] ) :

            // Return all the elements in a clean array
            slice.call( this );
    }
```

Версия Jquery **1.12.4**

Comment: Так вот же, буквально рядом: `jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( _i, method ) {jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) { ...` - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f810080e8e92278bb5288cba7cc0169481471780/src/ajax.js#L841

Comment: Спасибо, не ожидал найти его в таком виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал **Yaant** метод get определяется сразу после getScript. Там же с помощью метода each определяется и post метод.

```js
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {

        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        // The url can be an options object (which then must have .url)
        return jQuery.ajax( jQuery.extend( {
            url: url,
            type: method,
            dataType: type,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        }, jQuery.isPlainObject( url ) && url ) );
    };
} );
```